# Can I type LaTeX code in inkscape without a locally installed LaTeX distribution?

Tags: pdftex, code, inkscape, formulas

I use Inkscape 1.1 and I need to type LaTeX code (formulas and text in general) but I do not have a LaTeX distribution installed on my machine (I use Overleaf, online LaTex editor).

Example:
if I type "$\theta = 120 \degree $" in an Inkscape project, I would want to see:

[image: theta]

Can you suggest a way to perform this task without having to install a LaTex distribution on my machine? Is there an extension that performs this task?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. However, the latex installation doesn't necessarily have to be large, you can do a basic installation if that is your main concern.

Comment: Thank you @Zxcvasdf, can you suggest me a distribution of small size?

Comment: You could just use package `svg` in case you can upload your SVG files to Overleaf

Comment: Hi @mrpiggi, can you explain me further, please?

Comment: Well, a vague and unspecific question leads to this answer: Take a look at the manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/svg
In a nutshell: You can use LaTeX code directly in the SVG file and place it in your project directory. The package `svg` makes sure that Inkscape (running on the Overleaf backend) exports all the texts separately so that they can be compiled by LaTeX.

Comment: I don't imagine where is the problem. You can write `$a^2$` (for example) in Inkscape's text tool and you can export PDF+LaTeX file. Then you upload them to your Overleaf project and create your document using LaTeX or OpTeX here. Or I am missing something?

Comment: Hi @wipet, my goal is to type text and get its final form directly in inkscape, just as example: if I type $ \Theta = 120 deg $ I want to see the Greek letter symbol for \theta and the equation I inserted. (I 've inserted this example in the original question).

Comment: If you want to see the "final form" in inkscape, then you most likely need at least a minimal TeX installation. But do reconsider your options. If you use the svg package, or just export the image without text and add the text using LaTeX instead, the font and font size will match the rest of the document, which is better typographically.

Comment: @Giuseppe, have a look at https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-240003.2.2. You can try the "basic scheme" given there which should consume much of your device space.